# Unexpected behavior from the "yield from/await" statement?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, generator, cpython

## Consider the following asyncio code:

```py
import asyncio

class A:
    async def noop(self):
        pass
    async def f(self, name):
        print(f"{name} -> await")
        await self.noop()
        print(f"{name} -> return")
    async def f1(self):
        await self.f("f1")
    async def f2(self):
        await self.f("f2")
    async def f3(self):
        await self.f("f3")
    async def __call__(self):
        await asyncio.gather(self.f1(), self.f2(), self.f3())

class B(A):
    async def noop(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(0)

async def main():
    a = A()
    print(a.__class__.__name__)
    await a()
    print()
    b = B()
    print(b.__class__.__name__)
    await b()

asyncio.run(main())
```

**Output:**

```
A
f1 -> await
f1 -> return
f2 -> await
f2 -> return
f3 -> await
f3 -> return

B
f1 -> await
f2 -> await
f3 -> await
f1 -> return
f2 -> return
f3 -> return
```

A quick look at asyncio sleep's [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/04adf2df395ded81922c71360a5d66b597471e49/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L598-L624) gives us this:

```py
@types.coroutine
def __sleep0():
    """Skip one event loop run cycle.
    This is a private helper for 'asyncio.sleep()', used
    when the 'delay' is set to 0.  It uses a bare 'yield'
    expression (which Task.__step knows how to handle)
    instead of creating a Future object.
    """
    yield


async def sleep(delay, result=None):
    ...
    if delay <= 0:
        await __sleep0()
        return result
    ...
```

And a quick look at asyncio Task __step's [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/04adf2df395ded81922c71360a5d66b597471e49/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L253-L338) shows that it can only return control to the event loop if there is a yielded object and it's either `None` or a future-like object implementing the Future's class interface, namely a `_asyncio_future_blocking` attribute and a similar `__await__` method.

## Question:

The way the asyncio docs and examples are worded give the impression that a coroutine is always suspended when an `await` expression is run.

Since `await obj` is equivalent to `yield from obj.__await__()` and `yield` generally means "yield control/suspend", was it a oversight that `yield from` won't suspend generators if nothing was yielded?

```py
def outer():
    def inner(v):
        if v: yield
    yield from inner(False) # Not suspended
    yield from inner(True)  # Suspended
```

I understand that it wouldn't be feasible to suspend a non-yielding generator with `yield from`, but the fact that it's named `yield` and silently goes through (no StopIteration exception) caused quite a confusion in my mind and my code, when it wasn't suspending a task mid-execution.

Asyncio sleep's docs mention it without detailing the trick involved.

> Setting the delay to 0 provides an optimized path to allow other tasks to run. This can be used by long-running functions to avoid blocking the event loop for the full duration of the function call.

Comment: "The way the asyncio docs and examples are worded give the impression that a coroutine is always suspended when an await expression is run." - what gave you that impression? (It's a wrong impression, and not the design intent.)

Comment: "Since `await obj` is equivalent to `yield from obj.__await__()`" - this isn't true. `await` shares most of its implementation with `yield from` under the hood, but replacing `await obj` with `yield from obj.__await__()` is not a valid transformation.

Comment: I've started using Python's asyncio about a year ago and by reading on it, I got the impression that `await` always suspended, and since that's typical scenario, I didn't have any reason to question it, until now. Could you provide some examples of how `await obj` differs from `yield from obj.__await__()`?

Comment: Well for one thing, if you try to replace `await obj` with `yield from obj.__await__()`, you'll get a SyntaxError. For another, generators decorated with `asyncio.coroutine` or `types.coroutine` are awaitable, but don't implement `__await__`.

Comment: Indeed, I am aware of the SyntaxError one, although I meant it in a practical manner, rather than semantic one. Interesting, for the second example it's equivalent to "yield from obj.__iter__()".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exact question was:

"was it a[n] oversight that yield from won't suspend generators if nothing was yielded?"

The answer is that it absolutely, positively was not an oversight.  There is no room for any doubt.  Consider the following code, where `g` is a generator/iterator:

```
next(g)
```

or the equivalent:

```
g.__next__()
```

When you call this function, one of two things must happen.  It either returns an object, possibly None; or it raises an exception.  That is true of any Python function call.  It's how the language works.

So if "nothing was yielded" by `g`, there is no possible definition for the `next` function.  Returning `None` is a perfectly valid possibility, but "returning nothing" is not.

Consider:

```
def f1():
    yield None

def f2():
    if False:
         yield None

x1 = list(f1())
x2 = list(f2())

print(x1)
>>> [None]
print(x2)
>>> []
```

The first iterator yields one object, None.  The second iterator never yields at all.  Both are valid but they are not the same thing.

Thus there is no such concept as "suspending an generator/iterator if nothing was yielded."  All yields must yield some "thing" - some object.  That object is the returned value of the `next` function.  It is possible to design a programming language that works some other way, but it wouldn't be Python.

As for `StopIteration`, it is only raised when the iterator/generator returns.  When you use an iterator in an `in` expression, Python suppresses this error.  The only way I can think of to see an explicit StopIteration is to call one of the generator's low-level functions, like `next` or `send`.  Your expectation of seeing StopIteration from code like `yield from x`, where `x` yields nothing, is not correct.  This code:

```
x = []
yield from x
```

does not terminate a function, it's just a no-op.  It won't raise anything and the method will continue.

I hope this clarifies some of these issues.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am aware of most of the things you've pointed out; I think the main source of confusion for me (having used low-level async and coroutine libraries in C and C++), is that I was expecting a statement named `yield` to suspend the current execution (`yield` always does that, but `yield from` is more complex). Since `yield from` is used for asyncio and an `await` expression may or may not suspend the current task, it was somewhat confusing for me at first. Maybe `yield from` should've been named something else?

Comment: I've also found that `await asyncio.sleep(0)` is really bad to express your intention, if your intention is just suspending execution. People working on the code might not be aware of the trick being used and overlook it as no-op. A `@suspend` decorator that inserts `await asyncio.sleep(0)` as the coroutine's first expression, seems to be a lot clearer.

Comment: As you noted above, there is a difference between asyncio.sleep(0) and asyncio.sleep(x) where x is greater than zero.  The former doesn't always suspend the current task for a full event loop cycle.  See this answer for some details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69741177/run-multiple-async-loops-in-separate-processes-within-a-main-async-app/69762437#69762437.

Comment: I am not sure what I should look for in the linked answer. Did you link the intended answer? If so, could you point it out? According to https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/04adf2df395ded81922c71360a5d66b597471e49/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L321-L323 yielding `None` like `await asyncio.sleep(<= 0)` does, will always suspend the current task and resume it when the event loop iterates through ready handles at the next cycle.

Comment: Oh, I am so sorry.  You are right, I posted the wrong link.  This is what I meant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74493571/asyncio-sleep0-does-not-yield-control-to-the-event-loop/74505785#74505785.  It's a discussion of the difference between sleep(0) and sleep(0.001).  Again, sorry that I wasted your time.

Comment: Paul, don't worry about it. You're right about the order of execution, as `call_soon` appends the handle directly to the deque of ready handles, while `call_later` and `call_at` don't, relying on the event loop to append the handle when ready. Saying that `await asyncio.sleep(<= 0)` doesn't always suspend the task is incorrect though.

Comment: In the linked question, it still suspended the task, it just so happens that the other task wasn't ready at the next iteration of the event loop, had the first task used a very small value for sleep that would always evaluate ready at the next iteration (say, 0.0001), the second task would still execute first at the next iteration due to the ordering (call_soon first, call_later/at after), but they would still execute at the next cycle, with both getting suspended at the previous one.

Comment: That question is more of a synchronization issue, which can be solved by the synchronization primitives provided by the asyncio module, in my case, I wanted a way to enforce a task suspension without caring about the order of execution at the next cycle (which I believed a simple `await` was enough for all cases), for synchronization, I already use `asyncio.Lock` and `asyncio.Event`.

Comment: Moreover, awaiting on a future-like object will suspend the task, but that future could end up being resolved at the same cycle, causing the task to be resumed at the same cycle it was previously suspended.

Comment: I stand corrected for the above comment about future-like objects. They are scheduled with `call_soon`, so the callbacks only execute at the next cycle: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/04adf2df395ded81922c71360a5d66b597471e49/Lib/asyncio/futures.py#L161-L173

Comment: With that being said, it appears that `await asyncio.sleep(0.0001)` takes 2 cycles to resume (initial cycle suspends on `await future` and the next cycle schedules the ` __wakeup` callback), while `await async.sleep(<= 0)` resumes on the next cycle.