# Initiating opcua-asyncio Client in thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, opc-ua

In context of writing tests for an implementation using `asyncua.Client`, I'd like to (1) write a fixture for `asyncua.Server` and (2) call the function that eventually starts the client in a separate thread. A minimal example of what I'd like to achieve, without the complexity of writing `conftest.py` etc, is running something like below:

```py
import asyncio
import asyncua

import threading

async def listen(endpoint):
    async with asyncua.Client(url=endpoint) as client:
        print(f'OPC UA client has started {client}.')
        return

async def run_all(endpoint):
    server = asyncua.Server()
    await server.init()
    server.set_endpoint(endpoint)
    async with server:
        t = threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(listen(endpoint),))
        t.start()
        t.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(run_all('opc.tcp://0.0.0.0:5840/freeopcua/server/'))
```

This always leads to a `TimeoutError` in the line `async with asyncua.Client`.

Most examples I've found have two files called `server.py` for initializing `asyncua.Server` and `client.py` for initializing `asyncua.Client`. Then the server and client are started in separate terminals. However in order to run pytest, I believe both should start from the same entrypoint. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not mix async und threading, for such use cases. Use Tasks:

```
import asyncio
import asyncua


async def listen(endpoint):
    async with asyncua.Client(url=endpoint) as client:
        print(f'OPC UA client has started {client}.')
        return

async def run_all(endpoint):
    server = asyncua.Server()
    await server.init()
    server.set_endpoint(endpoint)
    async with server:
        task = asyncio.create_task(listen(endpoint))
        await task

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(run_all('opc.tcp://0.0.0.0:5840/freeopcua/server/'))
```

Comment: This solves the original question. How can this be extended when the `listen` function is an async generator? This is my actual use case - the client subscribes to OPC UA events and `yield`s on specific conditions.

Comment: You can use a Queue to send tasks to the client and wait for the result. https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html. Or you use a client class and add methods for each test case? Also you can have a look at the asyncua test cases and how they are structured.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the approved answer provided by Schroeder, an alternative using a ThreadPoolExecutor that worked in my case (where there is substantial multithreaded code):

```py
import asyncio
import asyncua

import multiprocessing
import concurrent.futures

async def listen(endpoint, condition):
    with condition:
        condition.wait()
    async with asyncua.Client(url=endpoint) as client:
        print(f'OPC UA client has started {client}.')
        return

def listen_sync(endpoint, condition):
    return asyncio.run(listen(endpoint, condition))

async def run_server(endpoint, condition):
    server = asyncua.Server()
    await server.init()
    server.set_endpoint(endpoint)
    async with server:
        with condition:
            condition.notify_all()
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

def run_server_sync(endpoint, condition):
    return asyncio.run(run_server(endpoint, condition))

async def run_all(endpoint):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    condition = multiprocessing.Condition()
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as pool:
        server_task = loop.run_in_executor(pool, run_server_sync, endpoint, condition)
        client_task = loop.run_in_executor(pool, listen_sync, endpoint, condition)
        await asyncio.gather(*[server_task, client_task])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(run_all('opc.tcp://0.0.0.0:5840/freeopcua/server/'))
```

Relevant references:

- [Tests of the opcua-asyncio library itself](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/blob/d52db7026a8f5f8d3a5aa690cc206824a21cd5d0/tests/conftest.py#L69), as suggested by Schroeder.
- [Run multiple async loops in separate processes within a main async app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69741177/run-multiple-async-loops-in-separate-processes-within-a-main-async-app)